# VideoJS, without source?

Tags: video.js

I'm loading videos dynamically, and everything's working fine. Currently, I load up the player with a small "placeholder" loop, which looks like a poster frame, but is actually a video. The reason I did this is because things acted strangely if I had a  tag, without a source (which is, in fact, I want on page load, and after videos finish).

But, on certain iOS devices, this causes a problem, since the video immediately runs full screen.

Is there a way to have an instance of VideoJS on a page, without a source, and do so without errors? Am I best to simply append a player on the fly, as I load videos dynamically?

Comment: Never mind, got mediaelements working in 5 mins...

Comment: can you give more info on mediaelements?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Video.js with empty source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19737396/video-js-with-empty-source)