# Video.js with empty source

Tags: video.js

Is there anyway I can place video.js without setting source on video tag?
Video.js fails without source when starts.

I want place video.js without source and set sourace from js api later.

same question here but no one answered.
[VideoJS, without source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831749/videojs-without-source)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66969177/7924858

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `preload="none"` on the video element

```
<video id="my_video" controls preload="none" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" data-setup="{}" />
```

Then load with the API

```
videojs("my_video").src([
  { type: "video/mp4", src: "http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" },
  { type: "video/webm", src: "http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" }
]);
```

Comment: thank you. Point was I shouldn't put empty "src" or <source>tag with empty "src". I thought "src" property was required to put <video>tag

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have to set the video `src` when the user opens up the modal.

The only thing that worked for me is the code below.

```html
<video controls preload="none" data-setup="{}">
  <source src=".mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>

<script>
$($modal).on("show.bs.modal", () => {
  videojs($video).src("/videourl.mp4");
});
</script>
```