# Setup video.js on angular2

Tags: angular, video.js

I am using video.js to work on my angular2 vidoes but couldn't make it work.
I am using video.js CDN in my index file.

```
<link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.11/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/5.11/video.min.js"></script>
```

I have a template file

```
<video *ngIf="videoUrl" id="{{id}}"
  class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered"
  controls
  preload="auto"
>
  <source src="{{listing.url}}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And component with video.js code inside `ngAfterViewInit`

```
export class ListingComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnDestroy {

id: string;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    videojs(document.getElementById(this.id), {}, function() {
      // Player (this) is initialized and ready.

    });
  }

}
```

The problem is, it shows error : "Cannot find name 'videojs'." that is inside `ngAfterViewInit`

I also tried installing video.js via npm and `import {videojs} from 'video.js` but that didn't work either.

Someone please help me out how to make video.js work with angular2. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First your are not initializing the videojs. So its showing the videojs undefined.

just find this below code:

```
declare var videojs: any;

export class ListingComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnDestroy {

  id: string;
  private videoJSplayer: any;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.videoJSplayer = videojs(document.getElementById('video_player_id'), {}, function() {
      this.play();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.videoJSplayer.dispose();
  }
}
```

html:

```
 <video 
   *ngIf="videoUrl" 
   id="video_player_id"
   class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered"
   controls 
   preload="auto">
   <source src="{{listing.url}}" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

check this link: [videojs plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/DrXJoH02IJLEdkYFu8HE/)    [plunker with answered](http://plnkr.co/edit/hpuO7mxk5TPZYc4f28nc?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, you are right.. Also, do you have any idea why it shows error when I refresh the page? The error is: `TypeError: The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)`

Comment: that means. your id is not unique, if you don't  want to change the id. check the updated answer

Comment: That way you cannot do. because videojs is initialized and disposed one time only. you can play another videos with change source of the video, it means we should append the video source for one videojs player only.

Comment: how can i reload the video player when im dynamically adding a video src?

Comment: How are you changing the videojs src ? just use method like ex: `changeSrc(){ this.videoSrc = 'https://yanwsh.github.io/videojs-panorama/assets/shark.mp4'; }` ,no need to do anything.its two way binding so video will play with new source url.

Comment: if you have some time on your hands to view my post on how im implementing videojs. Im able to change the video src but the video doesnt play??




https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820664/angular-2-updating-a-component-when-user-clicks-on-another-component/44821040?noredirect=1#comment76662701_44821040

Comment: check my answer for your question. I added my component code. I hope it help you.

Comment: @SathishKotha, I'm getting the same error: "TypeError: The element or ID supplied is not valid. (videojs)". I tried changing and giving the video player some unique id, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/hpuO7mxk5TPZYc4f28nc?p=preview .. check this plunker.

Answer (score 3):

Since Angular 2+ uses `ViewEncapsulation` by adding a `_ng-content-c*` attribute to each element under a component and adding the same attribute to the styles, you need to disable this feature to integrate third party libraries such as VideoJS.

Your component definition should be something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: 'component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    'component.scss',
    '../../../node_modules/video.js/src/css/video-js.scss',
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None, // This plus the sytleUrl are the important parts
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
}
```

Comment: Why should we do that? What's wrong with `_ng-content-c*` attribute?

Answer (score 3):

When using with Angular 4+ and Angular CLI, I found the best solution was to install via npm package then add videojs to scripts in the `angular-cli.json`, like so:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/video.js/dist/video.min.js"
]
```

From there, add this to your `typings.d.ts`:

```
declare const videojs: any;
```

Then init as per normal:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this._videoPlayer = videojs(document.getElementById('video'), {}, () => {});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing vide0.js in your Angular App

1.STEP->

paste `<link href=“//vjs.zencdn.net/5.11/video-js.min.css” rel=“stylesheet”>`. in index.html

2.Step

Add this in your component.html

```
<video id=“video” class=“video-js” controls  >
                 </video>
```

3.STEP

```
Add this in your component.css

@import ‘~video.js/dist/video-js.css’;
.video-js {
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;;
  }
```

4.Step-> in your Component.ts

```
import videojs from “video.js”; 


url:String=” “; //initialize this with video url
  player: videojs.Player;
```

**add this below code in your method or webhook method**

```
this.url = "assign video url";
           
            this.player = videojs(“video”, {
              controls: true,
              autoplay: false,
              muted: false,
              html5: {
                hls: {
                  overrideNative: true
                }
              }
            });
            this.player.src({
              src: this.url,
              type: “application/x-mpegURL”
            });
            this.player.on(“play”, () => {
              this.player.controls(true);//for controls make it true for other make it false
            });
            this.handleVideoAutoplay();

//you can use this method or ignore as well depend upon you
private handleVideoAutoplay() {
    const playButton = this.player.getChild(“bigPlayButton”);
    if (playButton) {
    //  playButton.hide();
      this.player.ready(() => {
        let promise = this.player.play();
        if (promise === undefined) {
          playButton.show();
          this.player.on(“play”, () => {
           // this.player.muted(false);
          });
        } else {
          promise.then(
            () => {
              playButton.show();
            },
            () => {
              playButton.show();
            }
          );
        }
      });
    }
  }
```