# Angular 2, Updating a component when user clicks on another component

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6, components

heres what im trying to achieve. Im trying to update a value in a `component` whenever a user clicks on another `component`. take a look at my code

here is my `app.component.html` file

```
    <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let tabs of videoTabs">

        <!-- this is where i want the user to click on -->
        <div class="tabs hvr-back-pulse">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="text-center col-sm-4">
                    <img src="{{ tabs.image }}" class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail">
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <small>{{ tabs.title }}</small>
                    <p>{{ tabs.description }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- eof click container -->

    </div>
```

here is my `app.component.ts` file *****UPDATED******

```
import { Component, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { VideoTab } from './videotab.model'; //importing our video class so we can use it

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  videoTabs: VideoTab[];

  // when angular creates a new instance of this componenet,
  // it calls the constructor function
  constructor() {
    this.videoTabs = [
      new VideoTab(
        'https://videosrc.video.net/video.png',
        'test',
        'test',
        'test'
      ),
      new VideoTab(
        'https://1111111.cloudfront.net/landingpage.mp4',
        'test',
        'test',
        'test'
      ),
    ]
  }

  setCurrentTab(tab: VideoTab): void {
    this.currentTab = tab;
  }
}
```

`videotab.model.ts` file

```
/**
 * Provides a Video object 
 */
export class VideoTab {
    constructor(
        public image: string,
        public description: string,
        public title: string,
        public videoSrc: string
    ) {}
}
```

this is where i would like the component to update the value in my `video tag` on the `src attribute` ****UPDATED TO USE VIDEO.JS********

```
<video id="background" class="video-js" loop controls preload="auto" width="100%" height="100%" poster="" data-setup="{}">
    <source [src]="currentTab?.videoSrc" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

right now my video tag isnt in its own component its currently in the `app.component.html` file where my tabs live. Thanks for all the help. I'm reading a book on how to develop Angular 2 apps, so this is all still new to me. thanks for all the help again!!! 
**** UPDATED **** 
When loading `src` attribute dynamically with tabs i get the following error message from video.js

`VIDEOJS: ERROR: (CODE:4 MEDIA_ERR_SRC_NOT_SUPPORTED) The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.` When i load my cloudfront link with my mp4 file in a new tab everything is loaded fine. Thanks for all the help

Comment: Since you're new to Angular 2, allow me to redirect you to [Multiple components interaction in Angular 2](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt3). I think that a whole tutorial will help you more than a few users on a forum.

Comment: awesome thanks!! haven't looked at the docs since i've been following this book. looking forward @trichetriche

Comment: Then you should, it's a real goldmine. I actually pinned the tutorials tab in my browser to have quick access to it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my situation.I am getting the video file from one component to this component with @input binding,its has the title,description as like your video tabs,I think your are not using videojs in your component html video tag.check this below code

**Update:** import [videojs playlist](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist) js files into your index.html and add the below code.it will change the video src dynamically of your videojsplayer

```
    import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input} from '@angular/core';
    import {SaveVideoFile} from '../../models/SaveVideoFile';

    @Component({
        selector: 'video-play',
        templateUrl :'./play-video.html',
        styleUrls: ['']

        }
        export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit, OnDestroy{
            @Input() selectedVideo: SaveVideoFile; // getting video file from another component
            currentTab: VideoTab;
            videoUrl: string;
            videoJSplayer: any;
            constructor(){}

              showVideo(video: SaveVideoFile) {  // getting one selectedVideofile from array of videos when you click on related videos
                console.log("videoComponent showVideo()");
                this.selectedVideo = video; // assining the new video file to existing selectedVideo 
                this.videoUrl = this.selectedVideo.videoPath; // assining the new videoSrcUrl to exsting videoSrcUrl 
                this.videoUrl = 'http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4';
                this.videoPlayListSource(this.videoUrl);
                }
             videoPlayListSource(videosrc:string){
              this.videoUrl = videosrc;
              const self = this;
              this.videoJSplayer.playlist([{ sources: [{ src: self.videoUrl, 
                          type: 'video/mp4' }]}]);

                 }
               ngOnInit(){
                this.videoUrl = this.selectedVideo.videoPath; // setting the selectedVideo file src here
                this.videoUrl = 'https://yanwsh.github.io/videojs-panorama/assets/shark.mp4'; 
                this.videoJSplayer = videojs(document.getElementById('example_video_11'), {}, function() {
                let player = this;
                this.ready(function() {
                this.bigPlayButton.hide();
                this.play();
               });
             });             
            }
            ngOnDestroy() {
                console.log('Deinit - Destroyed Component')
                this.videoJSplayer.dispose();
            }
        }
```

**html:**

```
<div>
    <video id="example_video_11" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
                controls preload="auto" width="630" height="320"
                data-setup='{"example_option":true}' [src]=videoUrl>
                <source [src]=videoUrl type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let tabs of videoTabs">
    <!-- this is where i want the user to click on -->
    <div class="tabs hvr-back-pulse" (click)="showVideo(tabs)">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center col-sm-4">
                <img src="{{ tabs.image }}" class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <small>{{ tabs.title }}</small>
                <p>{{ tabs.description }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- eof click container -->
</div>
```

Plunker : [Video Js Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vfn6E3M1Q6Ljvq4k2rTr?p=preview)

Comment: with my current implementation im able to dynamically change the `src` attribute in my `video` tag depending on which tabs i choose, but my video.js player wont load or play the video once i change the src. is there a method i should be calling? would you happen to know?

Comment: can you please update your question with videojs code? and what video path your using like mp4 or m3u8 ? and if any error please post.

Comment: i think src is not updating properly. can you check video path url in new tab.whether its playing or not

Comment: yes everything works fine. my cloudfront link works. here you can check for yourself https://d2s7o69x7ibgri.cloudfront.net/landingpage.mp4

Comment: can your add path like this.get the videoUrl from component `<source [src]=videoUrl type="video/mp4" />`

Comment: I mean store the video path in a variable and give that in source tag. check my answer

Comment: nothing.. i followed your instructions and the results were the same. nothing is being loaded. my thought process on this was that i need to reload the video?

Comment: maybe u can try, using my code and reproduce my same issue

Comment: im already able to change the video `src` dynamically based on which tab a user clicks tho...? is there a method where i can reload the video player from videojs?

Comment: Created Plunker with your code https://plnkr.co/edit/vfn6E3M1Q6Ljvq4k2rTr?p=preview

Comment: thank you for all your help. Im still very new to Angular 2 & OOP so it'll take me some time to read thru your implementation. I appreciate everything youve done.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept click on each tab by event binding (...) then save the clicked tab into a property currentTab of your component, then you can do a property binding with [prop]="..." to get back the current tab into the src of the video tag:

Template:

```
<div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let tabs of videoTabs">

    <!-- this is where i want the user to click on -->
    <div class="tabs hvr-back-pulse" (click)="setCurrentTab(tabs)">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="text-center col-sm-4">
                <img src="{{ tabs.image }}" class="rounded-circle img-thumbnail">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <small>{{ tabs.title }}</small>
                <p>{{ tabs.description }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- eof click container -->
</div>
<video>
    <source [src]="currentTab?.videoSrc">
</video>
```

Component:

```
export class AppComponent {

    currentTab: VideoTab;

    setCurrentTab(tab: VideoTab): void {
        this.currentTab = tab:
    }
    //.....
}
```

Comment: getting the following error message `Cannot read property 'videoSrc' of undefined` which seems pretty clear but my level of OOP makes it difficult to correct

Comment: awesome that worked. can u elaborate more on your answer? im still new to angular 2

Comment: It's using elvis operator (?) to prevent binding error in case currentTab is still undefined until a tab is clicked

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer has solved your problem